# Sorting of a UITableView with custom Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sorting

i have a custom UITableView that implements the delegate Methods and data Source
Methods. I would know sort the Table by the "Age" Property of my custom Object.

Where do i need to implement my sorting? and how can i sort?

My sorting would look like this:

```
- (void)sortPersonByAge{
 for(int i = 0; i < personArray.count(); i++){
   for (int j = i+1; j < personArray.count(); j++){
       Person * pJ = [personArray objectAtIndex:i];
       Person * pI = [personArray objectAtIndex:j];
       Person * pD; //Dummy

       if (pi.Age > pj.Age){
          [personArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:j];
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The sorting is also not 100% working.

Answer (score -1):

You should implement `compare:` method in your Person class and then call this method on the array holding the data:

```
NSArray * sortedPersonArray = [personArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Regarding the `compare:` implementation:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(Person *)person{
    if (self.Age > person.Age) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }else if(self.Age < person.Age){
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }else{
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can sort this way:

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSDate *first = [(Person*)a birthDate];
    NSDate *second = [(Person*)b birthDate];
    return [first compare:second];
}];
```

Or like this:

```
[self.array sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]]];
```

You can use this array in table like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Object *object = [self.sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = object.name;
    return cell;
}
```